# Google example universal music player build error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

I got build error like this after i download and imported the example
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':mobile:_debugCompile'.
Could not find com.google.android.support:wearable:1.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:

https ://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.2.0/wearable-1.2.0.pom  
https ://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.2.0/wearable-1.2.0.jar
         file:/Users/Jieyi/Downloads/android-UniversalMusicPlayer-master/mobile/libs/wearable-1.2.0.jar
         file:/Users/Jieyi/Downloads/android-UniversalMusicPlayer-master/mobile/libs/wearable.jar
         file:/Users/Jieyi/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.2.0/wearable-1.2.0.pom
         file:/Users/Jieyi/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.2.0/wearable-1.2.0.jar
         file:/Users/Jieyi/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.2.0/wearable-1.2.0.pom
         file:/Users/Jieyi/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.2.0/wearable-1.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         android-UniversalMusicPlayer-master:mobile:unspecified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed the Google Repository via your SDK Manager, and make sure that it is up to date. Version 1.2.0 of `com.google.android.support:wearable` is found in there. My guess, given your error, is that you have it installed but it is not up to date.